# Simply scroll Plugin Jumping to start

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi i am using  simply scroll plugin from this site http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

but i am having problem that when the scroller comes to the end and tries to loop back to the beginning instead of doing it with a smooth transition, it jumps back to the beginning which is a little rough on the eyes and clients are not liking it very much.

you can see the problem if you go to this site http://www.newwhey.com/ and look at towards the bottom where it says our retailers, and i have logo's scrolling down there once it gets to the end it jumps back, i am having same problems with other sites using this simply scroll any suggestions?

here is what i have for code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.simplyscroll.css" media="all" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
        autoMode: 'loop',
        width: 3000,
        startOnLoad: true
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**here is my css file for the simply scroll that is included in the top**

```
/* Container DIV - automatically generated */

.simply-scroll-container {
    position: relative;
}

/* Clip DIV - automatically generated */

.simply-scroll-clip {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* UL/OL/DIV - the element that simplyScroll is inited on    
Class name automatically added to element */

.simply-scroll-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}   

.simply-scroll-list li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}   

.simply-scroll-list li img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Custom class modifications - adds to / overrides above
    .simply-scroll is default base class */

/* Container DIV */

.simply-scroll {
    width: 1576px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
}

/* Clip DIV */

.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-clip {
    width: 1576px;
    height: 200px;
}   

/* Explicitly set height/width of each list item */ 
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
    float: left; /* Horizontal scroll only */
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: If you're having the same problem on multiple sites using the same plugin, I'd suggest there is something wrong with the plugin (or the way you are using it) and you might want to look into using a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you have the "width" value set on the plugin?

$("#scroller").simplyScroll({
autoMode: 'loop',
**width: 3000,**
startOnLoad: true
});

And than also:

```
$("#scroller .simply-scroll-list").css({"width":"auto"})
```

It seems like you re playing with the width of the elements outside the "knowledge" of the plugin and after it's init.

I suggest to try and remove that and simply use the container width from CSS, no need for JS here.

Comment: ok, so i took off the width from 

$("#scroller").simplyScroll({ autoMode: 'loop', width: 3000, startOnLoad: true });

also removed 

$("#scroller .simply-scroll-list").css({"width":"auto"})

but that doesn't seem to be helping either.

Comment: Try to remove the padding for the <li> items: #ourRetailers li {padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 20px;}  This seems to be adding size to scroller after the scroll is calculated. If this is the issue, you should probably try and add padding on the <img> tag, and make sure the css applies before the Script.

Comment: I guess i kinda gave up on trying to make simply scroll work at this point i found a different script that does the same thing and works much better here is the link to it  just in case anyone else is having the same problem and is much easier to use as well http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

thanks a lot for your help though i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

By exaggerating the overall ".simply-scroll" width to accommodate the scrolling elements it shouldn't skip and restart. ".simply-scroll-clip" will hide the overflow.

```
.simply-scroll {
  width: 6000px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em; 
}

.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-clip {
  width: 1576px;
  height: 200px;
}
```